# Why does changing a variable without a "mut" not throw a mutability error?

Tags: rust, mutability

I was reading the [Scopes and Shadowing](https://rustbyexample.com/variable_bindings/scope.html#scope-and-shadowing) section of *Rust By Example* and was confused about the mutability of variables. 
In this example there is a variable defined to a value of 1.

```
let long_lived_binding = 1;
```

It is later changed to

```
let long_lived_binding = 'a';
```

To my understanding, if you wanted to change a variable you needed to put the keyword `mut` in front of it. For example `let mut long_lived_binding = 1;` Why does the given example in *Rust By Example* not throw a mutability error?

Comment: Maybe not an exact duplicate, but that may be close enough?

Comment: I'd agree that the let-rebinding question answers this already. But for the OP, the short version is that the second 'let' does not modify the first variable but instead creates a *new* variable with the same name, which doesn't interfere with mutability.

Comment: Indeed, and as an example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f7aaf36001fda16ea6756f8147d7df3f&version=stable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutability prevents modification of a variable, but it will not prevent you introducing a variable with same name using `let`. The difference is subtle but noticeable. Shadowing can change the type of value. Mutability can't.

Shadowing:

```
let x = 2;
let x = "String";
```

Mutability:

```
let x = 2;
x = 3; // will not compile because the variable that's immutable was assigned twice.

let mut x = 2;
x = 3;
x = "String"; // will not compile because you changed the type.
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=934c6875e70ef1428d8952313c9badb8&version=stable)

Answer (score 2):

The 1st variable get shadowed by the 2nd one. Rust allows that. It's as if you defined 2 different variables with different names.